# The 'Visual Studio Build Manager Package package' did not load correctly. VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Everything was working fine with this project (very small project) and when I try to open it or anything else (or start a new project) after installed VS2013 Update 2, I'm getting this error message.

Tried repairing the install twice, once before and one after uninstalling Resharper (only plug in I use), anyone else see this or know the solution?

[image: New Error after installing VS2013 Update 2]

Answer (score 1):

Never knew why it happened... Solve was to uninstall VS2013 completely.  Reboot.  Reinstalled... tried to launch.  Crash.  Installed Update 1.  Tried to launch.  Crash.  Installed Update 2.  Launched fine, all good now.

I figure something didn't install correctly with the first Update 2 (and subsequent repairs) to cause the original problem.  But something DID install correctly to prevent compatibility with VS2013 original or update 1.

Oh well, works now.